# how to access function variable outside if statement php

Tags: php

How can i access function variable out side if else statement as you can see when i declared `opType == "Anand"` than code will run but i use post man to saw result

```
if (!(empty($_POST)) & isset($_POST)) {
    $opType = $_POST["opType"];
    if ($opType == "insertFuelEngineMap") {
        //insert into fuel_engine_capacity_mapping setValuesForCreation(false); 
        $query = "INSERT INTO fuel_engine_capacity_mapping(cf_mapping_id,capacity_id) VALUES ('$cf_mapping_id','$capacity_id')";
        $loginResult = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0) {
            $userdata = array('status' => '200', 'msg' => "insertlol into fuel_engine_capacity_mapping successfully", 'mapping_id' => $link->insert_id);
        } else {
            $userdata = array('status' => '404', 'msg' => " Cant fuel_engine_capacity_mapping " . mysqli_error($link));
        }
    }
    if ($opType == "anand") {

        function addition() {
            $GLOBALS['z'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];
        }

    }
}
addition();
echo $z;
```

Comment: please format your code properly.

Comment: you don't think that it is a bad approach to declare function basis of `if/esle`. You should create a function in a class and call it according to your requirements

Comment: I dont actually understand what you are asking.

Comment: I dont understand those people asking questions and never answering nor validating answers ...

Answer (score 1):

You can return the value :

```
//Modify you function so it will return the result
function addition() {
    return $GLOBALS['z'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];
}
```

Then :

```
//Catch variable and echo
echo $z = addition();
```

I hope it's what you want, because your question is not clear.
Moreover, you 'll have error if `$opType` is different than `anand` because function 'll be called but it 'll not exist.

It should be better to declare it in any case and not only if `$opType === 'anand'`.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a function inside and if statement, only if some variable is set  and then calling it outside that if statement where you **do not check** that that variable is set a plan for disaster!

Instead define the function in the main body of the code and call it with parameters, and just return the computed value

```
<?php
function addition($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

$z = addition($x, $y);
echo $z;
```